# C/UNIX Execute a function once every x milliseconds

Tags: c, unix, posix

How do I execute a function once every 1000 milliseconds using alarm() or sleep? I want the program to do something else if the function does not execute or complete in 1000 milliseconds.

EDIT: added Pseudocode

```
while(true) {
alarm(1000);
execute function;
sleep(1000);
alarm(0);
}
```

Now if alarm(1000) signals SIGALRM is this where I could call the other function?
I'm new to this sort of stuff so not even sure if I am using it right.

Comment: Are you just looking for a Linux/Unix function that will sleep for 1 second?

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is not very difficult; would you need to handle 200 ms or 1200 ms too?

Comment: I want to eliminate cumulative drift.  If the function does not execute exactly once during the 1000 millisecond period the system will call another function...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How crisp is the requirement, ie, how much jitter can you tolerate?

What version of UNIX?

Basically, if this is a hard deadline -- it sounds like one -- you're going to need to do some special stuff, because basic UNIX isn't really  a hard-real-time system.

Let's assume for the moment that you mean Linux.  You'll want to

- use *[nice](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nice)(2)* to raise the process priority
- use a fine-grained timer, as with *[ualarm](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm)(3)*

That will probably *do*.  If you need finer grained, or more predictable, timing, then you probably need to write a kernel extension to it can be driven with a kernel timer. (Solaris has some improved support for hard-real-time, but it's still not really a hard real-time system.)

Life will get considerably easier if you can use a real-time Linux or UNIX.  Here's a [list of some options](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Realtime-Linux-Software-Quick-Reference-Guide/). Here's an [article you might find usefui.](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/A-comparison-of-hard-realtime-Linux-alternatives/)

**Update**

You should also look at *[nanosleep](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep)(2)* or *[setitimer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer)(2)*.  Notice that all of these say the interval is *at least* the one in the argument.  If you have a hard deadline, you need to wait for somewhat less than the actual interval and then figure out what to do with any change on your thousand millisecs.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this function on Linux to "sleep" in milliseconds:

```
void Sleep(unsigned int milliSeconds)
{
    struct timespec req = {0};

    time_t seconds  = (int) (milliSeconds / 1000);
    milliSeconds    = milliSeconds - (seconds * 1000);
    req.tv_sec      = seconds;
    req.tv_nsec     = milliSeconds * 1000000L;

    while (nanosleep(&req, &req) == -1)
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    /* Act */
}
```

If you need tighter delays, the normal way to do it is to call select() with no fds and a low timeout.